# How to implement step by step async process using RxJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, rxjs

I'm going to send data to the server from the array in turn. Each next dispatch should be invoked after complete previous request. How can I implement it using RxJS?

P.S. It is angular 4 application.

Comment: use `flatMap()`

Comment: Could you add some Code ?
What have you tried which error occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to chain your `Observables`, use `.flatMap()`. It's the same as `.then()` in `Promise`

Suppose you have 3 HTTP call functions in your service, called `firstRequest()`, `secondRequest()` and `thirdRequest()`. You can chain them like this

```
myService.firstRequest()
    .flatMap(result1 => {
        //do something with result1 from firstRequest
        return myService.secondRequest(result1)
            .flatMap(result2 => {
                //do something with result2 from secondRequest
                return myService.thirdRequest(result2);
            });
    })
    .subscribe(result3 => {
        //finally do something with your result3 that is from thirdRequest
    });
```